# Getting daily playcount of a track using SoundCloud API

Tags: soundcloud

I am getting the total play count of a track using Sound Cloud API. I am just wondering if there is a way to get daily play count and/or weekly play count.

If its not possible is there a work around which i can implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SoundCloud API offers a [/tracks resource](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) that displays a single track's "playback_count" (total number of plays). The API documentation does not specify a way to obtain the daily play count and/or weekly play count.

Some suggestions for implementing your idea:

1. Send an e-mail to api@soundcloud.com detailing a feature request
2. Ping [@SoundCloudDev](https://twitter.com/SoundCloudDev) on Twitter detailing a feature request
3. Write a program (or sets of programs) that implements background jobs to download daily snapshots of a track's play count.

Cheers!